# What do you mean by splitting field? Find the splitting field of $x^5 -1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

Okay, first of all sorry for a stupid question. Now what I know is -

**Splitting Field:**
Let $K$ be a field and let $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2+\cdots + a_n x^n$ be a polynomial in $K[x]$ of degree $n>0$. An extension field $F$ of $K$ is called a splitting field for $f(x)$ over $K$ if there exist elements $r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_n \in F$ such that 
$(i)$ $f(x) = a_n (x-r_1) (x-r_2)\cdots (x-r_n)$, and 
$(ii)$ $F = K(r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_n)$

There is another concept: For $f(x)\in F[X]$, which is a polynomial of degree $n\ge 1$, there exist an extension $E$ of $F$ of degree at most $n!$ in which $f(x)$ has $n$ roots.

Let's take an example as $x^4+1$, then
$$x^4+1 = (x^4+2x^2+1)-2x^2 = (x^2+1)^2 - (\sqrt{2} x)^2
= (x^2 + 1 + \sqrt2 x)(x^2 + 1- \sqrt{2} x)$$

Let $r$ be the root of $(x^2 + 1- \sqrt2x)$, then
$r = -\dfrac{\sqrt2 \pm \sqrt{2-4}}2 = \dfrac{\sqrt2(\iota-1)}2, \dfrac{-\sqrt2(\iota+1)}2 $

So, $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\iota)$ is the smallest field containing $\dfrac{\sqrt2(\iota-1)}2$ 
So it's the splitting field right? 
$[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\iota):\Bbb{Q}] = [\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\iota):\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)][\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\iota):\Bbb{Q}] = 2\times 2 = 4$ 
( Because $\sqrt2$ satisfies an irreducible polynomial $x^2-2$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ hence $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2):\Bbb{Q}] = 2$. Similarly $\iota$ satisfies an irreducible polynomial $x^2+1$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, therefore it satisfies $x^2+1$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ also hence $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\iota):\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)]=2$ ) 
Is my explanation correct?

So first we need to find the factors of $x^5 - 1$. 
This equation can be simplified to $$x^5-1= (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)(x - 1)$$
And now I am stuck here. I will update the solution if I'm able to get the roots. 
Thanks.

Comment: by an chance is this your assignment question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field

Comment: What you may need, far more than the solution to this question, is to have a good look at whatever teaching materials are available to you. If you have no idea what a splitting field is, there are probably a lot of other important things you've missed, and getting on top of them is more necessary than getting the answer to this question.

Comment: The roots of $x^5-1$ are the numbers $e^{2\pi ij/5}$, $j=0,1,2,3,4$. Also, when you post here, it's much easier to read what you've written if you use MathJax to format the formulas. There's help available onsite for that.

Answer (score 0):

First off, we need a ground field. I'll assume that this is $\Bbb Q$, but it might as well be $\Bbb R$, or a finite field, or any of a number of other options.

The splitting field of $x^5-1$ over $\Bbb Q$ of the smallest field which

1. Contains $\Bbb Q$
2. Contains all roots of $x^5-1$

You are allowed to use things you know from complex analysis to *find* these roots of $x^5-1$, if you so desire. Once you've found them, say $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$, the splitting field is simply the extension of $\Bbb Q$ by these roots: $\Bbb Q(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$. If this expression can be simplified (for instance, if some of the $x_i$ are superfluous), then I suggest you simplify it.

Comment: I've now been downvoted twice now, with no explanation. If the intent behind the downvote is to tell me that my answer isn't helpful, then please tell me in what way it is unhelpful. If I don't know what I did wrong, I can't do a better job next time.

Comment: I'm guessing that the downvoters don't like the question and don't think anyone should answer it.

Comment: @AnkitKumar You asked "What do you mean by splitting field?", and I have answered that as simply as I know how. You said "i need the solution of this question" and I told you exactly how to find it, as simply as I know how. If I made the answer any simpler, I would have to cut out important details, and then the answer would be wrong. I could just have told you "The splitting field is $\Bbb Q(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is ..." but that's not a fun answer to write, and making that choice is my prerogative as answerer on this site.